# Migrating sqlite3 to postgres in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

I have read several posts and watched the railscast on migrating from sqlite3 to pg and all of them seem to have conflicting settings and I have not seen anyone run into the error I'm getting.  I have data locally that i do NOT care about.  If it gets destroyed that's fine.

Here is what I have done.

Changed database.yml from this:

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

To this:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
database: app_name_database
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

One thing I did notice about this file and some of the examples is that I do not have encoding, username, or password.  Is this necessary?

I updated my gem file from this:

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

To this:

```
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

Following the instructions - the railscast says to rake db:create:all.  However, when I run this I get the following error in console:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?  Are there rake tasks that need to be done before this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed and configured PostgreSQL locally?

Comment: Yeah - psql --version is psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you started the Postgresql database ?  This is how I start mine - pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start ?

Comment: so you run from the command line: "pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start" and it starts your pg server?

Comment: Unlike SQLite which staarts automatically you need to start Postgresql, at least in developmetn, whenver you start work for the day.  Further info http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html  -  Pierre

Comment: This was it.  Railscasts failed to mention that.  Make sure pg is started before rake db:create:all. thanks!

Comment: apologies comannd is - pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast 2- Also you can (I haven't done so) start the database as part of the autostart - see http://blog.willj.net/2011/05/31/setting-up-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-development-on-os-x/